# Why is this boost::container::string & std::string comparison not working as intended?

Tags: c++, string, boost, string-comparison, std

Say you have a std::string and a boost::container::string just like this :

```
std::string                stdString     =   "This is a test";
boost::container::string   boostString   =   "This is a test";
```

Say you want to compare their content ; the following is not possible because we cannot compare their types :

```
stdString == boostString                 // no operator "==" matches these operands
```

You then choose to use both of their methods .c_str() to get a char* from each string. Not being sure if this does effectivly compare the strings, you try it :

```
stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str() // compiles, but comparison returns false
```

You then try to only use c_str() method from the std::string :

```
stdString.c_str() == boostString         // compiles, and comparison seems fine
```

You try the opposite out of curiosity and it works as well :

```
stdString == boostString.c_str()         // compiles, and comparison seems fine
```

So the question is, why does these two latter comparisons seem to work fine when the first one did not ?

Bonus question : Is this an unreliable way of comparing the content of these strings ?

Full code sample :

```
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string stdString = "This is a test";
  boost::container::string  boostString;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      boostString = "This is a test";
      std::cout << "Both strings have the same content." << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      boostString = "This is z test";
      std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Both strings are different from each other." << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str() comparison is : ";

    if (stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str())
      std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "false" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "stdString.c_str() == boostString comparison is         : ";

    if (stdString.c_str() == boostString)
      std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "false" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "stdString == boostString.c_str() comparison is         : ";

    if (stdString == boostString.c_str())
      std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output given by the sample :

```
> Both strings have the same content.
> 
> stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str() comparison is : false
> stdString.c_str() == boostString comparison is         : true
> stdString == boostString.c_str() comparison is         : true
> 
> 
> Both strings are different from each other.
> 
> stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str() comparison is : false
> stdString.c_str() == boostString comparison is         : false
> stdString == boostString.c_str() comparison is         : false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `stdString.c_str() == boostString.c_str()` you don't compare the strings, you compare the *pointers* returned by each objects `c_str` function. And they will most certainly not be equal. If you want to compare strings C-style use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

---

The reason e.g. `stdString.c_str() == boostString` works is because `boost::container::string` have a non-explicit constructor taking a `const char*` argument, just what `stdString.c_str()` is returning. That means `stdString.c_str() == boostString` is actually equal to `boost::container::string(stdString.c_str()) == boostString`, which compares two `boost::container::string` objects.

Same for `stdString == boostString.c_str()`, it's equal to `stdString == std::string(boostString.c_str())`.

---

If you need to mix `std::string` and `boost::container::string`, and need to use some specific operators with that mix, then you can always overload those operators yourself.

For example

```
bool operator==(std::string const& stdString, boost::container::string const& boostString)
{
    // If the length of the strings differs, then they're not equal and we return false
    // Otherwise, compare the actual contents of the strings
    return stdString.length() == boostString.length() &&
           std::memcmp(stdString.c_str(), boostString.c_str(), stdString.length()) == 0;
}

bool operator==(boost::container::string const& boostString, std::string const& stdString)
{
    return stdString == boostString;  // Calls the previously defined operator== overload
}
```

Both are needed so you can use either type on either side of `==`.

Also note that I'm using [`std::memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) for the comparison, because either string could contain embedded zeros, which would otherwise act as the string terminator for `std::strcmp`.

Comment: Rather, use `memcmp()`, as it's not necessarily a 0-terminated string, there might be embedded 0s.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and is well explained :D

Comment: And thank you for the operator overload tip, I really don't know why I didn't think about it, that will make life so much simpler :>

Comment: Just for completion, you would need also both `operator!=`, so you can compare for equality and for inequality.